# Guide or approval for ANTLR example

Tags: sql, antlr, relational-algebra

I have an `AlgebraRelacional.g4` file with this. I need to read a file with a syntax like a CSV file, put the content in some memory tables and then resolve relational algebra operations with that. Can you tell me if I am doing it right?

Example data file to read:

```
cod_buy(char);name_suc(char);Import(int);date_buy(date)    
“P-11”;”DC Med”;900;01/03/14    
“P-14”;”Center”;1500;02/05/14
```

Current ANTLR grammar:

```
grammar AlgebraRelacional;

SEL     : '\u03C3'
        ;
PRO     : '\u220F'
        ;
UNI     : '\u222A' 
        ;
DIF     : '\u002D'
        ;
PROC    : '\u0058' 
        ;
INT     : '\u2229'
        ;

AND     : 'AND'
        ;
OR      : 'OR'
        ;
NOT     : 'NOT'
        ;

EQ          : '='
            ;
DIFERENTE   : '!='
            ;
MAYOR       : '>'
            ;
MENOR       : '<'
            ;

SUMA    : '+'
        ;
MULTI   : '*'
;


IPAREN  : '('
        ;
DPAREN  : ')'
        ;
COMA    : ','
        ;
PCOMA   : ';'
        ;
Comillas: '"'
        ;

file  : hdr row+ ;
hdr   : row ;
row   : field (',' field)* '\r'? '\n' ;
field : TEXT | STRING | ;

TEXT   : ~[,\n\r"]+ ;
STRING : '"' ('""'|~'"')* '"' ;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest you that read this document (http://is.muni.cz/th/208197/fi_b/bc_thesis.pdf), It contains usefull information about how to write a parser for relational algebra. That is not ANTLR, but you only has to translate the grammar in BNF to EBNF.